# Is it possible to make an edit and put it in the review queue (after gaining the auto-approve privilege)?

Tags: support, privileges

Okay, silly billy question, but it seems that because I have a high-enough score, my edits on questions and answers which are not mine are auto-approved. But if I wish to just have a second opinion before validating, is there a way to do so? It's for instance to double-check the grammar since I am not a native English speaker, or because I'm just not ultra-confident enough on a topic.

If there's no way, I guess I will just need to be even more cautious. But to fill my curiosity to the brim (or dry it down, depends on the way you look at it ;p), is there a specific reason for this, like, you always need to be sure of your edits/your edits should majoritarily improve the question/You lose too much time on tiny things, ya tortoise perfectionnists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only option is to log out, or open a private browsing window (or even another browser) so that you're browsing Stack Exchange as an anonymous user. Anonymous users can suggest edits too; however, if it's approved, it will show as 'edited by ♦ Community' instead of your account.

An alternative is to make the edit anyway, but leave a comment for the author to double-check. If your edit is [substantial enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135961/295232), they will get notified of the edit anyway.

For more details, see [Can I submit an edit for approval after earning 2k reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103270/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Oh, I wondered too about the "edited by community" edits. Thought it was deleted users.

Comment: That is possible too; Community takes the credit for them as well.

Comment: I'm not really happy with that solution : Looks to me this possibility was a function hole that never reached the top spots in dev stack priority, more than an intended feature... But peck, I'm too lazy to fight this over, I'll just be twice as more cautious ˁ˚ᴥ˚ˀ.

Comment: Interesting info.. I didn't know there was an active Community account with an anonymous submit option.